# Can you write a query to look up a value in another table based on modifying the foreign key in Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a query in Django where I query a value from a table based on both the value of the foreign key and a modification to the foreign key. Consider an example database that stores the names, teams, and records of a team in one table that links to the league's revenue in another:

```
class League(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    revenue = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    year = models.ForeignKey(League, max_length=4)
    record = models.TextField(max_length=10)
```

How would I write a query so that I could create a table that included the name of the team, the year, this year's revenue, and the previous year's revenue?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a many to many relationship:

```
class YearlyReport(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    revenue = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    yearly_reports = models.ManyToManyField(YearlyReport)
```

And this is how you can add the reports:

```
t = Team(name='Test Team')
yearly_report_for_2018 = YearlyReport(revenue=100000, year='2018')
yearly_report_for_2017 = YearlyReport(revenue=50000, year='2017')
t.yearly_reports.add(yearly_report_for_2018)
t.yearly_reports.add(yearly_report_for_2017)
```

This is how you can get the reports:

```
r = YearlyReport.objects.get(team__name='Some Team')
print(r.year, r.revenue)
```

more in official docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you know how to get the last year's revenue without changing the database schema? I can't change the schema for the project I'm working on at the moment.

Comment: Do you know if writing a subquery of the team table with the year increase by one, so that we could look up the previous year's revenue through the team's current revenue field, would be useful at all?